# How can I properly use moment inside of pug?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, momentjs, pug

I'm trying to use moment to format a date in PUG.
This is my code:

```
  table(style='width:50%', border='2')
      tr
        th Event Title
        th Date
        th Coin
        th Name
        th Description
      each event in data.body
        tr
          td(style='text-align: center') #{event.title['en']}
          td(style='text-align: center') #{moment(event.date_event).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
          td(style='text-align: center') #{event.coins[0].symbol}
          td(style='text-align: center') #{event.coins[0].name}
```

I've tried looking for examples here but I couldn't make it work with the ones I found.
PS: I have the library installed and imported to all my local app files already.

Can anyone help me with that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

or

```js
script(src='moment.min.js')
```